# как вытянуть данные (широту и долготу) с JSON и с помощью Location.distanceTo

Tags: java, android, json, android-location

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как вытянуть данные (широту и долготу) с JSON и с помощью `Location.distanceTo` нужно вычислить и вывести расстояние в листвью...(именно не выходит реализовать ( `Location.distanceTo` )

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_POINTS = "Points";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_PARTNER_NAME = "partner_name";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";




    private static String url = "";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new GetPoints().execute();

    }



    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseJSON(String json) {
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                // Hashmap for ListView
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PointsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray Points = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_POINTS);

                //////////////////


                // looping through All
                for (int i = 0; i < Points.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Points.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_ADRESS);
                    String partner_name = c.getString(TAG_PARTNER_NAME);


                    HashMap<String, String> points = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    points.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    points.put(TAG_ADRESS, email);
                    points.put(TAG_PARTNER_NAME, partner_name);

                    // adding
                    PointsList.add(points);
                }
                return PointsList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetPoints extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PointsList;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            PointsList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /*
              Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
              */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, PointsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_ADRESS, TAG_PARTNER_NAME}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.partner_name, R.id.distance});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Чтобы вам помогли, вам для начала нужно скинуть сам JSON

Comment: http://80.78.46.241:48090/ConditionallyConstantInformation/SnapshotDatabase/Points.JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не имею против `JSONObject`, но есть более удобные велосипеды.

Добавьте себе в проект библиотеку `GSON` в gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

Отлично.

Теперь создадим класс `GeoPoints`.

```
public class GeoPoints {
    private ArrayList<PointsData> Points;

    public ArrayList<PointsData> getPoints() {
        return Points;
    }

    static public class PointsData {
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

Отлично в этом объекте у нас будут храниться все координаты.

Теперь упростим ваш AsyncTask до безобразия;

```
 private class GetPoints extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyPoints> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected MyPoints doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonStr, MyPoints.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyPoints result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /*
              Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
              */
           //тут создаем кастомный адпатер для ListView
        }

    }
```

Метод `ParseJSON` можно просто удалить.

Теперь по поводу того, как подсчитать дистанцию до точки.
Для начала вам нужно получить текущие координаты устройства, это и будет отправной точкой. Сами же расчеты могут быть выглядеть так

```
float[] arrayOfFloat = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, andLatitude, andLongitude, arrayOfFloat); 
float distance = arrayOfFloat[0]; //дистанция в метрах
```

Или вот так

```
Location startLocation = new Location("startLocation");
startLocation.setLatitude(startLatitude);
startLocation.setLongitude(startLongitude);

Location endLocation = new Location("endLocation");
endLocation.setLatitude(endlatitude);
endLocation.setLongitude(endlongitude);

float distance = startLocation.distanceTo(endLocation);
```

В любом из `startLatitude` и `startLongitude` - место положение устройства, а `endlatitude` и `endlongitude` координаты из вашего JSON, ну `distance` это расстояние в метрах.

Ну и конечно вам для всего этого нужно сделать `Кастомный` адаптер для `listview` ;) для работы с классом `MyPoints` и подсчета расстояния. Но я бы настоятельно рекомендовал делать `ВСЕ` расчеты в `AsyncTask` (в методе `doInBackground`), а в список отдавать уже `готовые` результаты.